# How do I allow the user to select which file to read? c++

Tags: c++, text-files, readfile

I want to allow the user to select a text file, and then for the text file to be read by c++ for content analysis.

This code opens any file selected by the user:

```
    system("explorer/select,c:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe");
```

the calc.exe command at the end means it executes the selected file, but I want the file to be read, not executed, how do I do this?

Comment: You're coming at this backwards. Instead of executing a shell command using `system`, you want to know how to pop up a File Prompt dialog from your program, and get the result back to your program. (Then how to read files.) That (for you) is the job of the Windows API, so I suggest having a look through MSDN for useful functions.

Comment: Console application or GUI application?  Very important.  With console applications, you need to prompt the User.  With GUI applications, you can have a File Selection dialog box.

Comment: Have you tried the `std::ifstream` constructor or `open` method?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it's a console application, but I'm unsure of how to create file prompts for the user.

Comment: For a console application:  `std::cout << "Enter filename: "; std::cout.flush();`

Comment: you can either use the API `ShellExecute()` or if you want a popup dialog from which the user can browse the file to open then consider read about windows `OPENFILENAME` struct and the API `GetOpenFileName()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows, to show the standard "file open dialog" picker you want to invoke [GetOpenFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927(v=vs.85).aspx).  Easy example found via Google [here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/217307/a-simple-getopenfilename-example).

Comment: @Thomas Yes, it does.